# T-SQL, string comparison with leading digit using parameters returns a false positive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if someone can explain this behaviour?

```
DECLARE @RandomParam1 NVARCHAR
DECLARE @RandomParam2 NVARCHAR
DECLARE @RandomParam3 NVARCHAR
SET @RandomParam1 = '0HelloWorld'
SET @RandomParam2 = '9HelloWorld'
SET @RandomParam3 = '15HelloWorld'

select 1 where '0' = @RandomParam1  -- true
select 1 where '0' = '0HelloWorld'  -- false

select 1 where '9' = @RandomParam2  -- true
select 1 where '15' = @RandomParam3 -- false
```

Why does a string comparison with parameters yield a different result than without parameters? And why does it claim that '0' = '0whatever'?

I get that it may be that the parameter tries to compare it as numbers, but then the last example should be true aswell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **default length** for `NVARCHAR` is 1. Your three parameters effectively all contain just one single character.

If you change your declarations to

```
DECLARE @RandomParam1 NVARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @RandomParam2 NVARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @RandomParam3 NVARCHAR(32)
```

you will get the behavior you were expecting.

[nchar and nvarchar](http://When%20n%20is%20not%20specified%20in%20a%20data%20definition%20or%20variable%20declaration%20statement,%20the%20default%20length%20is%201.)

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified no length for your variables, resulting in a default length of 1.

```
DECLARE @RandomParam1 NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @RandomParam2 NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @RandomParam3 NVARCHAR(20)
```

Added the `LENGTH` to your variables.